# JavaScript - Mqtt Sending and Reciving Image

Tags: javascript, java, image, mqtt

I am currently working on a project in which I want to send an image as ByteArray to a mosquitto broker with java to the topic images. 
The subscriber of these Topic is a JavaScript application, which should convert the ByteArray,made in Java, back to an Image. 
The reception of the image is working well, but the image cannot be shown correctly.

What I got so far:

Java Code to Publish an Image

```html
public void doDemo(){
        try {
            client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.56.1", "Camera1", new MemoryPersistence());
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            client.connect(connOpts);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
            File imgPath = new File(Reciver.class.getResource("Card_1007330_bg_low_quality_000.png").getPath());
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

            // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
            WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
            DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

            message.setPayload(data.getData());
            client.publish("spengergasse/building-b/2.14/images", message);

        } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

JavaScript to show the image

```html
function onMessageArrived(r_message){
 console.log(r_message);
  
 document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + convert(r_message.payloadBytes);
}

function convert(buffer) {
 var binary = '';
 var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
 var len = bytes.byteLength;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
 }
 return window.btoa(binary);
}
```

After Reciving the Image I am gettin this:

[image: Page + Console]

Maybe someone could help me out.
Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function convert(buffer) {
  var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');
  return btoa(decoder.decode(buffer));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to use blobs. Instead of converting the array to base64 which is terribly slow an error prone if not done correctly, you create a blob from the input array and assign it to the .src property like this:

```
var blob = new Blob([r_message.payloadBytes], {type: 'image/png'});
document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```